# How to retrieve data from an hyperlink in an excel file?

Tags: python, excel

I have some hyperlinks stored in a local excel file. All of them are in one column. E.g

```
| A  
| ----------------------------------| 
| http://vocab.getty.edu/tgn/8699749|
| http://vocab.getty.edu/tgn/8704811|
| http://vocab.getty.edu/tgn/8702341|
| http://vocab.getty.edu/tgn/1063874|
| http://vocab.getty.edu/tgn/1063880|
| http://vocab.getty.edu/tgn/7032551|
|-----------------------------------|
```

Each link points to a page from which I would extract the information related to the field xl:prefLabel and store the result in the column B

Openpyxl could be the solution?

The expected result should be something similar to

```
| A                                 | B                      |
| ----------------------------------| ------------------------
| http://vocab.getty.edu/tgn/8699749| tgn_term:1005671253-fr |
| http://vocab.getty.edu/tgn/8704811| tgn_term:1005683546-de | 
| http://vocab.getty.edu/tgn/8702341| tgn_term:1005684314    |
| http://vocab.getty.edu/tgn/1063874| tgn_term:64447         |
| http://vocab.getty.edu/tgn/1063880| tgn_term:64453         |
| http://vocab.getty.edu/tgn/7032551| tgn_term:1001213640    |
|-----------------------------------|------------------------|
```

Comment: Why didn't you use the ```excel``` tag?

Comment: You could use **urllib** to get the data from your website in a _JSON_ format, then use the library of your choice to edit your excel file with the data you've retrieved from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to use Pandas slicing:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request

all_hyperlinks = pd.read_excel(path_to_excel_file, index_col=None, header=None)
first_hl = all_hyperlinks.loc[0, 0] # Get the first hype link
contents = request.urlopen(first_hl).read()
```